# How to prevent Pandoc from overwriting existing files when extracting media?

Tags: pandoc

I'm using Pandoc to convert a bunch of DOCX files into RST.

```
pandoc -f docx -t rst file1.docx -o file1.rst --extract-media=.
pandoc -f docx -t rst file2.docx -o file2.rst --extract-media=.
pandoc -f docx -t rst file3.docx -o file3.rst --extract-media=.
...
```

Images within each file are being extracted into the `media` directory as expected (`media/image1.png`, `media/image2.png`, ...), but my problem is that images from each file overwrite those from the previous one.

The solution I have so far is basically to convert each file into a separate directory:

```
mkdir file1
pandoc -f docx -t rst file1.docx -o file1/file.rst --extract-media=file1
mkdir file2
pandoc -f docx -t rst file2.docx -o file2/file.rst --extract-media=file2
mkdir file3
pandoc -f docx -t rst file3.docx -o file3/file.rst --extract-media=file3
...
```

Is there any option or way to have all images in the same directory? Maybe some kind of *media prefix*?

Comment: use `--extract-media=media1`, which will create a folder named `media1`

Comment: Thanks @mb21 that's the solution I'm currently using, but I'd like to have everything in the same directory

Comment: I guess then you'd have to rename the files yourself and change the references in the rst files with a custom [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)